# Is it possible to debug a wear 3 app without an internet connection?

Tags: android, bluetooth, wear-os, android-wear-2.0, samsung-galaxy-watch-4

I have written an Android Wear OS app and would like to debug it on my Samsung Galaxy Watch 4, which runs Wear 3.

Previously, I was using a Fossil gen. 6, which ran Wear 2, and was deploying my application to the watch using ADB/Bluetooth debugging, which worked well.

Now, I am having trouble doing the same with with my Galaxy Watch 4. ADB will "connect" to the device, but it is always listed as offline when I run `adb devices`, and Android Studio does not recognize it as an option to deploy to. Looking for a solution I found that the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/get-started/debugging) states that debugging over bluetooth is exclusive to devices running Wear OS 2.

The other option is to debug the app over wifi. However, the watch rejects my university network-- probably because it's captive-- and unfortunately, I do not have access to a personal hotspot.

The Galaxy Watch 4 does not have a USB port, so I cannot connect it directly.

I am wondering if there is any workaround to this issue which will allow me to debug my application on my watch without access to an internet connection.

Thanks!

EDIT: Ended up solving the issue by connecting both the dev laptop and watch to an offline network off a wireless router my mentor had laying around. It isn't connected to the internet but having them both on the network is sufficient to debug over wifi using ADB.

Comment: I'd suggest using a mobile as a temporary hotspot to get your computer and watch on the same network.  But effectively you can't use ADB with Galaxy Watch 4 unless you have an acceptable Wifi network.